# Action script 3: Running a function if a generated number is of a certain value (that refreshes every 3 seconds)

Tags: actionscript-3, random, setinterval

I am trying to make two objects move toward each other if a generated number is of a certain value (in this case < 5).

I tried making a function to generate the number, and I used setInterval to refresh the number every 3 seconds. But the objects (cell and virus) still move toward each other every time. I can't figure out what is wrong in the code. I have tried modifying it for 2 days now, but I need help! Mind nudging me in the right direction?

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Movement)

var minLimit:uint = 1;
var maxLimit:uint =10;


setInterval(someNum,3000)

function someNum():int{
var range:uint = maxLimit - minLimit;
var randomNumber:int = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
return randomNumber;
}


function movement(){
if(cell.x < virus.x)
{
    if(someNum() < 5){

    cell.x += 1;
    virus.x -= 3}
}

}

function Movement(e:Event){
movement();
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance. I am pretty new to coding...

Comment: Do you think you can learn to program and do it yourself?

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that without getting help on the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Movement)

var minLimit:uint = 1;
var maxLimit:uint =10;
var someNumber:int = 6;

setInterval(someNum,3000)

function someNum():void{
var range:uint = maxLimit - minLimit;
someNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;

}


function movement()
{
   if(cell.x < virus.x)
   {
     if(someNumber < 5){    
      cell.x += 1;
      virus.x -= 3
     }
   }

}

function Movement(e:Event){
movement();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you a lot for spending time on helping me. It seems as if it doesn't work, though. The cell and virus always move toward each other without any interruptions (when the number refreshes after 3 seconds, for example).

I tried making the if condition to "someNumber < 1" to test this further, and the results always remain the same.

I also got an error, and added "var" to "interval = blablabla", but I guess that was just a typo :P

I'll keep on trying to fix it, but if you find a solution, I'd appreciate if you could post it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome! It works really nice. But how do I make it so that the random number is different every time I start the program? Because they always move to each other at first, and then maybe stop (which is awesome in itself, but it'd be perfect if they didn't always move from the start).

Thank you again, you are awesome! :)

Comment: I changed the code again. check it. You need to set someNumber = 6 (greater than 5 in your case) to stop the object's move intially. Also mark this answer as correct ;)

Comment: Oh right, okay! 

Didn't know about the marking system. Thank you!!